# Count in array where value is 0

Tags: php, arrays, count

I'm really stuck here. Im having an array looking like this below. 
And now I would like to count postStatus where postStatus = 0, for all of the arrays.

So in this case there would be 2. But how do I do this?

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [postId] => 1
        [postHeader] => Post-besked #1
        [postContent] => Post content #1 
        [postDate] => 2011-12-27 17:33:11
        [postStatus] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [postId] => 2
        [postHeader] => Post-besked #2 
        [postContent] => POst content #2
        [postDate] => 2011-12-27 17:33:36
        [postStatus] => 0
    )
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loop the outer array, check if there is a postStatus, increment a value to keep that count and you're done...

```
$postStatus = 0;
foreach($myarray as $myarraycontent){
    if(isset($myarraycontent['postStatus']) && $myarraycontent['postStatus'] == 0){
        $postStatus++;
    }
}
echo $postStatus;
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that isset() can be used but a better pratice is to use array_key_exists because if $myarraycontent['postStatus'] is NULL, it will return false. Thats the way isset() works...

Comment: OP only wants to count the items where `postStatus` is `0`, this will count regardless of value.

Comment: @Madmartigan Where do you see that? I see "I would like to count postStatus", doesn't say anything about them being 0, you assume that because of the data he's printed...

Comment: Read the question title, OP left us a misleading example.

Comment: Indeed... i just saw it... could have been bigger and i'm not sure i'd have seen it :P

Comment: Well, I want to count how many of the results that has the postStatus as 0. I need this for a Private Message application, where I have to show, how many messages is new.

Answer (score 3):

```
$count = count(
  array_filter(
    $array, 
    function ($item) {
        return isset($item['postStatus']);
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: I think I like this better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Compact and concise :)

```
$postStatusCount = array_sum(array_map(
    function($e) { 
            return array_key_exists('postStatus', $e)  && $e['postStatus'] == 0 ? 1 :  0; 
    } , $arr)
);
```